# Laravel update function

Tags: laravel

I need to change the value of columns from "0" to "1" after click on the Validate Button in my Application.

The column is saved as "0" by default.

I need to find the right ID of the invoice and update this value. So I tried this code, but my update function is not working.

In view: (Each button got the ID of my invoice)

```
<form action="{{route('Invoice.update', ['id' => $in->id])}}" method="post">
    {{method_field('patch')}}
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="hidden" name="catid" id="catid" >
    <button type="submit"  data-catid="{{$in->id}}"></button>
</form>
```

Controller: (Find the Id invoice from value f input)

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::findOrFail($request->catid);
    $invoice->validate = 1;
    $invoice->save();

    return back();    
}
```

route:

```
Route::resource('Invoice','ValidateController');
```

Errors:

- No query results for model [App\Invoice].

Edited 
Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `Route::resource('Invoces', 'ValidateController)`, the route to update your Invoice must provide an `ID` of the invoice which you whan to update and the update method in your controller must look like this

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    // here goes the code to update the invode
}
```

You are passing `test` as value of the ID which the `invoice.update` route expect.

```
<form action="{{route('Invoice.update', ['id' => $in->id]}}" method="post">
```

If you want the route behave the way you specifie you make create a custom route for `invode.update`. For that you must except the `update` when you are registering the invoce resource and define another route for the update after

```
Route::match(['put', 'patch'], '/invoce/update', 'ValidationController@update');
Route::resource('Invoce', 'ValidationController')->except(['update'])
```

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for ur attention, when i add update with ur response, i got now the id, but i have the error : No query results for model [App\Invoice].

Comment: That means there isn't any Invoice with correspond to the ID that you specify

Comment: It is sir, they wrote me an ID that exist in my database

Comment: Is the `ID` that you get from the request the same as which is in your database? verify the value of the ID. If It's the right `ID` it can't return that error. The error which you get  means eloquent haven't found any invoice with that id

Comment: Yes, the request return : http://localhost:8000/Invoice/59  
And  i have an invoice with the id=59

Comment: Try with `dd(Invoice::find($id));` put it as the first line in you update method just to know if you can find the right invoice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180766/discussion-between-yves-kipondo-and-yassine-j).

Comment: Thank you sir, i had to change Invoice::findOrFail($request->catid) by Invoice::find($id)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that

> My code can't find the invoice ID (catid)

?

You have invalid form action `{{route('Invoice.update', 'test')}}`. Remove `test` property - `{{route('Invoice.update')}}`

And I advise use lowercase in the route names: `{{route('invoice.update')}}` and `Route::resource('invoice', 'ValidateController');`

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for ur attention. When i remove 'test' i got error message: Missing required parameter